# Next Js Home Page is giving me 404 Page not found After Next JS upgrade to Next JS 11.1.2

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, versionupgrade

After upgrading my Next.JS version to Next 11.1.2 My HomePage is redirecting me 404 not found .While Other Routes are working as expected.

I do not have any thing specific in my app.js that sould block my home page . Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle to figure out why the home/index.page was not loading for me . I figured out my index.jsx was inside a folder called index, and Next.js would not recognize that as the starting point of the application. As I took the file out of the folder and placed index.jsx directly under Pages folder , it started working like a magic.

Hope this is of some help to somebody else.