# Next Js Home Page is giving me 404 Page not found

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

[image]Just started NextJS version 11.1 and all routes are working first time the website is launched. However when I click on the Home Page/index.js, I get the 404 Not Found. Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks

Here's the index.js code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> 
      </Head>
      <Hero>
        <Heading>NEXT</Heading>
      </Hero>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of the `Link` element ?

Comment: Here's the code of my index.js  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> 
      </Head>
      <Hero>
        <Heading>NEXT</Heading>
      </Hero>
    </>
  );

Comment: @Jamil please update your question with your code rather than in a comment as it's not readable. ("```javascript" for js highlighted fenced code blocks).

Comment: @2SCSsob please check...thanks. im using a navbar for all page routes

Comment: Where is this index.js located ? under the pages folder ? Your question needs to be updated with more information so we can understand better, where is the problem

Comment: What do you mean by "when I click on the Home/index.js" ? If you mean that you have a "home" button in your navbar, you could check the link in the button and/or `console.log()` the click event to see what happens. Without further information as @AppCity stated, we can't really help you.

Comment: sorry guys im new to stackoverflow...my problem is similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726303/next-js-home-page-is-giving-me-404-page-not-found-after-next-js-upgrade-to-next

Comment: @AppCity yes its under the pages folder

Comment: Could you show us your folder structure and also the place where you navigate to home ?

Comment: @AppCity please check thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "/index" from the Link and just add "/"

That is the default route for index.js

Comment: You are awesome..Thanks so much